# Use prettier to convert kebab-case attributes to camelCase in JSX

Tags: javascript, jsx, prettier

I'm writing a script to automatically convert an SVG file into a JSX (or TSX to be more specific) file. I've used prettier to clean up the code at the end of the process but I have noticed that none of the parsers that prettier has to handle JSX formatting convert kebab-case attributes to valid JSX CamelCase ones.

So I end up with this:

```html
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="[svg paths here]" clip-rule="evenodd" />
```

when I need it to be this:

```html
<path fillRule="evenodd" d="[svg paths here]" clipRule="evenodd" />
```

This is an issue as I have no control over the source file that someone could feed into this function and I don't want JSX errors appearing in my apps as a result.

I realise I could just do a manual find-and-replace but if there is a prettier option that I'm missing, I'd much prefer to use that.

Comment: looks like prettier 3 is now doing that out of the box AFAICT